# input type color alternative to always show color picker

Tags: html, colors

I want an actual element always shown in a form on my page which allows users to pick colors, without first having to open up a little window by clicking the input type="color".

Is this possible without making my own color picker from scratch, or would I have to create my own element to manipulate the value of the input type="color"?

Comment: It is not going to happen with an input element.

Comment: You can use color picker with Bootstrap